# Segfault with GtkFileChooserDialogNative

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, gtk

I simply try to open a file through a dialog using Gtk3. This is the code I am using, no modifications at all:
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.FileChooserNative.html#typical-usage-gtkfilechoosernative-typical-usage

The window opens fine but when I try to open the file, it segfaults. According to `gdb`:

```
Thread 1 "a.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:76
76              VPCMPEQ (%rdi), %ymm0, %ymm1
```

Using `debuginfod` of course. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Some backtrace from `gdb`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:76
#1  0x00007ffff7e1b948 in __GI__IO_puts (str=0x0) at ioputs.c:35
#2  0x00005555555551d6 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb28) at main.c:6
```

Comment: What DE are you running?

Comment: I use GNOME 42.